# how can I install Firebase authentication in terminal using cocoa pods?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

When I enter pod 'Firebase/Auth' it isn't installing the pod. Its saying this: [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Auth` required by `Podfile`

  None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Auth`.

  You have either:

  - out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
  - mistyped the name or version.
  - not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

  Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

  [!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

I have said in the pod file - pod 'Firebase' and that is installing fine, but I don't know why 'Firebase/Auth' isn't installing.

This is using swift and Xcode is any of you were wondering, please can someone suggest what I can do to solve this, thanks

**This is the pod file:**

```
platform: ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target: 'Lifelapse' do
pod 'Canvas'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

EDIT:
The solution was just to 'pod repo update' which worked perfectly. However now I have 27 error messages - [image: error messages] Please help!

Comment: can you include your pod file?

Comment: I've added it into the question at the bottom:)

Comment: Try running 'pod repo update' first. And if that gives you any kind of error messages, run 'pod repo update --verbose' and see what problems you're specifically getting.

Comment: YES!!! thanks! that did the trick:)

Answer (score 0):

I did more or less than the guy told us 
but my steps were a little different:

1. On the Terminal: go to your project folder:

   1.1 `sudo Desktop/YourApp`

   1.2 `YOURMAC:YourApp Fernanda$ sudo pod init`
2. Change your file Podfile to:

   ```
   # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
   platform :ios, '8.0'

   target 'YourApp' do
     # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!

     # Pods for YourApp
   pod 'Firebase'

   end
   ```
3. On the Terminal:  `pod install`
4. Now, change your file Podfile again to:

   ```
   # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '8.0'

   target 'YourApp' do
     # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
     use_frameworks!

     # Pods for YourApp
   pod 'Firebase'
   pod 'Firebase/Auth'

   end
   ```
5. On the Terminal: `pod update`

Answer (score -1):

try update platform version 8.0 to 9.0

```
platform: ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target: 'Lifelapse' do
pod 'Canvas'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

Comment: That hasn't worked, it's still giving me the same message in terminal